# How to run a bash script from a Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a Makefile from which I want to call another external bash script to do another part of the building. How would I best go about doing this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just like calling any other command from a makefile:

```
target: prerequisites
    shell_script arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Regarding your further explanation:

```
.PHONY: do_script

do_script: 
    shell_script arg1 arg2 arg3

prerequisites: do_script

target: prerequisites
```

Comment: but I need to run the script before the prerequisites

Comment: @Matthew, then your makefile is set up incorrectly.  Make a new `.PHONY` target that your prerequisites depend on, and run the script in that target.

Comment: Edited with more for your case.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps not the "right" way to do it like the answers already provided, but I came across this question because I wanted my makefile to run a script I wrote to generate a header file that would provide the version for a whole package of software.  I have quite a bit of targets in this package, and didn't want to add a brand new prerequisite to them all.  Putting this towards the beginning of my makefile worked for me

```
$(shell ./genVer.sh)
```

which tells make to simply run a shell command.  `./genVer.sh` is the path (same directory as the makefile) and name of my script to run.  This runs no matter which target I specify (including `clean`, which is the downside, but ultimately not a huge deal to me).

Comment: whatever the right way is supposed to be, this is the only answer that made sense to me!

Answer (score 13):

Each of the actions in the makefile rule is a command that will be executed in a subshell. You need to ensure that **each command is independent**, since each one will be run inside a separate subshell.

For this reason, you will often see line breaks escaped when the author wants several commands to run in the same subshell:

```
targetfoo:
    command_the_first foo bar baz
    command_the_second wibble wobble warble
    command_the_third which is rather too long \
        to fit on a single line so \
        intervening line breaks are escaped
    command_the_fourth spam eggs beans
```

Answer (score 13):

Currently using Makefile, I can easily call the bash script like this:

```
dump:
    ./script_dump.sh
```

And call:

```
make dump
```

This also works like mentioned in the other answer:

```
dump:
    $(shell ./script_dump.sh)
```

But the downside is that you don't get the shell commands from the console unless you store in a variable and `echo` it.

Comment: In the last case, the output of `$(shell ./script_dump.sh)` will be considered a new command to be run after running the script, leading to `No such file or directory` errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is best practice, but the most straightforward approach I've found is to simply use `bash`, if your terminal has it:

```
run_file:
    bash ./scripts/some_shell_script.sh
```

This negates the need to alter the permissions of the file first then by executing directly i.e. via `./scripts/some_shell_script.sh`. Alternately to *source* the command in the spawned make process, the following 2 methods below will also work (the `./` is optional).

```
run_file_source:
    source ./scripts/some_shell_script.sh

run_file_source_alt:
    . ./scripts/some_shell_script.sh
```

Within your terminal, the following can then be run.

```
$ make run_file
```

---

An extended make entry to run a python file after running a shell script to activate the virtual environment to run it in (by chaining commands with `&&`):

```
run-python:
    @bash -c "source ./scripts/python/activate_env.sh && \
    python src/python_scripts/main.py"

run-python-alt:
    @source ./scripts/python/activate_env.sh && \
    python src/python_scripts/main.py
```