# How to execute a post-build command in NetBeans to run Windows/DOS batch file?

Tags: netbeans, makefile, post-build

I'm attempting to do something which should be very simple. After executing a build in NetBeans IDE I wish to run a Windows executable for some post-processing.  This executable needs to be run in a different directory than the project directory, so I need to change directory first. So, in fact I need the post-build step to run a batch file with these two steps.

Now most IDEs have an option for running a post-build step. This includes MPLAB which is built on NetBeans, and in which I could run the batch file above and all works fine. But NetBeans 7.2 IDE does not have this as a project option, so I figured I have to use the Makefile. I'm not an expert in Makefiles, but it seems I can't just call a Windows batch file from a Makefile. When I do this it attempts to execute the batch commands as make commands instead of OS commands.

I have three options - does anyone know if any are possible:

1. Run a post-build step in NetBeans without using a Makefile.
2. Run a batch file from a Makefile.
3. Do a 'cd' command and run an exe from a Makefile. (So I don't need a batch file.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497675/running-a-bash-script-from-a-make-file

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-which-directory-it-is-stored-in?rq=1